# Redirecting to the View from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have two controllers and and two views in my application.

1. Home Controller & Index View
2. Susbcription Controller & Index View.

I have a save method in the Subscription Controller. I want to call the Home Controller/ Index View after the save is complete. When I do the following I get the page not found error.

return Redirect("Home/Index");

OR

return View("Home/Index");

Could somebody tell me why is the view not getting called ?

Thanks and regards
Ranjit Menon

Comment: Pretty sure this is the issue: check the method signatures again - the first parameter is the action, the second is the controller. You are looking for an action with a strange name `Home/Index` which isn't going to work - try `Redirect("Index", "Home")`

Comment: Ah as someone pointed out it's `RedirectToAction` not an overload of `Redirect` - so use that instead :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `RedirectToAction` as mostly your action Return type is `ActionResult` :

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
```

or if you want to return simply view without action, then:

```
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

See more [**details here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

### Note:

The second is not recommended you should use first one to redirect to **Home/Index**, you should not use `Rediect` in asp.net mvc you should use `RedirectToAction`

Answer (score 0):

To add on top of Ehsan's answer, I want to point out how to pass parameters around if you need to do this in the future:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult PaymentBillMe(string pledgeAmt, string month, string radioBtn, string btn) 
    { 
      return RedirectToAction("PaymentConfirm", new
                        {
                            paymentSelection = radioBtn,
                            paymentAmt = pledgeAmt,
                            selectedMonth = month
                        });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PaymentConfirm(string paymentSelection, string paymentAmt, string selectedMonth)
    {
     //Do something with parameters...
     return View();
    }
```

Here I am passing the radio button selection, pledge amount, and the selected month to the payment confirm method, doing something with those parameters and then returning that view.